# Is there a way to identify or detect data skew in Hive table?

Tags: sql, performance, hadoop, hive, skew

We have many hive queries that take lot of time. We are using tez and other good practices like CBO, using orc files etc.

Is there a way to check / analyze data skew like some command? Would an explain plan help and if so, which parameter should I look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explain plan will not help in this, you should check data. If it is a join, select top 100 join key value from all tables involved in the join, do the same for partition by key if it is analytic function and you will see if it is a skew.

Example:

```
select key, count(*) cnt
   from table
  group by key
 having count(*)> 1000 --check also >1 for tables where it should not be duplication (like dimentions)
  order by cnt desc limit 100;
```

`key` can be complex join key (all columns you are using in the join ON condition).

Also have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061613/2700344

Comment: thanks for the pointer, i will surely check and get back. this really helps.