# union grouped result sets in Hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I need to break a Hive query grouped by an ID column over the quarters of calendar year 2018. Below is how I am currently going about it I would like another option to achieve the same result with fewer queries.

--Query 1 quarter 1 2018  plus three identical queries for Q2,Q3,Q4

```
Create TABLE Q12018 stored as ORC as
select
ID,
count(1) as cnt, 
sum(revenue) as revenue,
sum( (CASE
    WHEN condition1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)) as metric1,
sum( (CASE
    WHEN condition2
    THEN revenue
    ELSE 0 END)) as metric2,           

sum( (CASE
    WHEN condition3
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)) as metric3,
sum( (CASE
    WHEN codition4
    THEN revenue
    ELSE 0 END)) as metric4                            
from mainTable
where month between 201801 and 201803
group by 
ID;
```

--Query 2

```
Create TABLE combined2018 stored as ORC as

select * from  Q12018 

union all

select * from  Q22018 

union all

select * from  Q32018 

union all 

select * from  Q42018 ;
```

--Query 3

```
Create TABLE Agg2018 stored as ORC as

Select 
ID,
Sum(cnt),
Sum(revenue),
Sum(metric1),
Sum(metric2),
sum(metric3),
sum(metric4)
from combined2018  
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like at the end you are aggregating all the quarterly results, grouped by ID.If the end result is the aggregation of the quarterly results then change the where clause to include the entire year range to achieve the same end result.

```
select
   ID,
   count(1) as cnt, 
   sum(revenue) as revenue,
   sum((CASE  WHEN condition1  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)) as metric1,
   sum((CASE  WHEN condition2  THEN revenue  ELSE 0 END)) as metric2,           
   sum((CASE  WHEN condition3  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END)) as metric3,
   sum((CASE  WHEN condition4  THEN revenue  ELSE 0 END)) as metric4                       
from mainTable
where month between 201801 and 201812
group by ID;
```

Comment: I need to break the query into quarterly chunks because the size of the main table, our cluster is shaky when it comes to queries over long date ranges.  My original was exactly as you suggest but there were to many performance issues.

Comment: @hghghghg All you heed then is to tune proper parallelism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296562/2700344 and: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491316/2700344