# How do I generate a random number _only once_ for a Hive query?

Tags: hive

I have code that looks like this:

```
set hivevar:foo=rand();
select ${hivevar:foo} from my_database.my_table;
```

I think, even with the variable substitution, `rand()` is still being called once per *row*. How do I just set `foo` to a random number once per *query*?

I can think of other solutions, but I'd like to keep everything contained to one hive query instead of patching together something uglier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it in a one-row subquery and cross join with your query. The subquery should be executed once

```
select s.rnd, a.col, etc
  from my_database.my_table a
      cross join
  (select rand() as rnd) s
;
```

Comment: Awesome. This helped me understand what was going on and what I actually wanted to do: Take the cartesian product between a scalar and a vector, like what cross join does. Thanks! However, I think I'm going to use something similar to what @VMykyt has, because it seems like cross join takes a little longer to run.

Comment: @matthiasdenu It is the same cross join because `FROM rand, source_table` without `ON` condition is a cross join. You better to use ANSI join syntax

Comment: @matthiasdenu See also this for better understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843832/2700344

Comment: @matthiasdenu Normally it should run map-join, if not, check this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154414/2700344

Answer (score 2):

This code calls rand() for every row:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT st.col1, st.col2, RAND() AS col3
FROM source_table st;
```

This code calls rand() only once:

```
WITH rand AS (
  SELECT RAND() as col3
)
INSERT INTO dest_table
SELECT st.col1, st.col2, rand.col3
FROM rand, source_table st;
```