# Hive Multiple Joins Very Slow

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have Table A with 60 million records and Table B with 20 million records and I am joining those tables based on key columns . `(inner join on a.id=b.id)`

I am able to fetch the results within 10 minutes . After that for validating another column in Table C (I am joining the result generated from Table A and Table B ) with Table C(30 million records) and joining the column b with column c.`(inner join on b.prfl_id=c.prfl_id)`

But the query is very slow and it is running for more than 30 minutes and even then result is not generated. Any suggestion to get the results fast.
Thanks in advance for your suggestion .

Regards,

Saravanan

Comment: What is the result size of first join in terms of rows?

Comment: Also, what is the format of the underlying data?

Comment: Result size of 1st join is lakhs of data and I am not sure of exact count  ...

Comment: Format is delimited text format.

Comment: Convert tables to a more efficient format like orc. Then, try implementing a partitioning strategy and rewriting queries to leverage the partitions. Consider denormalizing the data to avoid expensive joins, since Hive is not a traditional RDBMS.

Comment: Try leveraging a map-side join. This can help speed things up if one table is quite small compared to the other.

Comment: 1. Check joins do not duplicate data (check join keys unique where they should be). 2. Increase parallelism and use vectorizing. See this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487306/2700344