# Insert rows in table based on date logic - sql/hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, calendar, hiveql

Need mysql/hive query which can insert new rows for missing dates from a date range for all IDs. Initial table looks like this:-

```
ID   Date        Value
1    01-Feb-2018  50 
2    02-Feb-2018  10
```

Let's assume *start date*=`01-Feb-2018` and *end date* = `2-Feb-2018`

The final table should like this

```
ID   Date         Value
1    01-Feb-2018  50
1    02-Feb-2018  0
2    01-Feb-2018  0
2    02-Feb-2018  10
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please replace images with text

Comment: Hi All, I have updated the question to be more specific. Replaced the images with text. Please advice further. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it will be reopened,  looks quite good to me after it was edited

Comment: Thanks leftjoin. The post is still on hold. I will wait for further advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute start_date and end_date variables in this example with yours and also see comments in the code:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2015-07-01; --replace with your start_date
set hivevar:end_date=current_date; --replace with your end_date

set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true; --this enables map-join
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=25000000; --size of table to fit in memory

with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range, check it's output
select date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) as dt 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff(${hivevar:end_date},'${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
) 
--insert overwrite table your table  --uncomment this after checking if you need to overwrite your table
select s.ID, 
       s.dt,
       case when t.id is null then 0 else t.value end as value --take existing value for joined, 0 for not joined
       --also you can do simply NVL(t.value,0) as value if no NULLs are allowed in your_table.value
  from
       (--this subquery will give all combinations of ID and date, which should be the result
        select d.dt, IDs.ID
          from date_range d cross join (select distinct ID from your_table) IDs 
       ) s          
          left join           
       your_table t on s.dt=t.date and s.id=t.id --join with existing records, check your table column names  
 order by s.id, s.dt --remove this if ordering is not necessary
;
```

Comment: Hi leftjoin, thanks a lot for sharing the query and the logic . It works perfectly for me.

Comment: The query works fine on relatively small datasets but struggles with big datasets ( few billion rows). Hive executes the query in 4 jobs, the first three jobs gets completed but the fourth one gets stuck at reduce = 33%. Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Added settings for mapjoin (see updated answer). Also try to move on Tez and tune reducers parallelism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487306/2700344

Comment: Also please provide explain plan